# Regular expression for email address in Arabic

Tags: php, preg-match

**EDITED**

I googled to write a custom regular expression for my web application, and still I can't get what I wanted.

I want to check if a string passes this pattern or not:

```
*STRING*STRING INCLUDING ALL CHARS*STRING INCLUDING ALL CHARS#
```

for example:

```
*STRING*the first string تست یک*the second string تست دو#
```

Should return TRUE

```
*sdsdsd*the first string تست یکthe second string تست دو#
```

should return FALSE(because it's not the pattern as *STRING*STRING*STRING#)

```
$check = preg_match("THE RULE", $STRING);
```

I'm asking for THE RULE here, sorry if I asked my question in a wrong way...

Comment: Reading the docs for [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match) would be a good start, if your problem is that you don't want it to return `TRUE` (which, by the way, it doesn't, it returns an integer). Look at the `$matches` argument.

Comment: I always prefer to use `filter_var()` for validating emails in PHP. Although I'm not sure how much that will help you with your problem. Checkout the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: It seems I asked my question in a wrong way, I need a preg_match() pattern to check the whole string

Comment: Short answer: There isn't one.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions for email validation. Use `filter_var()` instead. You could split the string by `*`, shift off the email element, join it by `*` again and then use a regex to validate. E.g. `$parts = explode('*', $str); if (array_shift($parts) !== '' || !filter_var(array_shift($parts, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) || !strlen(array_shift($parts)) || strlen($parts[0]) < 2 || substr($parts[0], -1) != '#') { // fail } else { // success }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a string has this pattern or not: `*STRING*STRING*STRING#`:

```
if (preg_match(
    '/^       # Start of string
    \*        # Match *
    ([^*]*)   # Match any number of characters except *
    \*        # Match *
    ([^*]*)   # Match any number of characters except *
    \*        # Match *
    ([^#]*)   # Match any number of characters except #
    \#        # Match #
    $         # End of string/x', 
    $subject, $matches))
```

Then use

```
filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

to check whether the first group might contain an e-mail address.

Comment: thanks, just what I wanted, and no way to check if the first string is a valid email address, right?

Answer (score 3):

No need for a regular expression, use `filter_var()`:

```
function checkEmail($str){
    $exp = explode('*', $str);
    if(filter_var($exp[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && $exp[2] && $exp[3] && substr($str, strlen($str)-1, strlen($str)) == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$valid = checkEmail('*example@example.com*the first string تست یک*the second string تست دو#');
```

Comment: I'm asking for a regullar expression as PHP preg_match(), the function you're offering has nothing to do with my question, thanks anyway

Comment: @behz4d: It is impossible to validate an e-mail address with a regex. Don't even go there. Besides, you will still need to check if a syntactically valid e-mail address really has a mailbox associated with it (and that someone reads the mails in that mailbox).

Comment: Email validation these days is quite hard. Remember that are emails with `.42` and tons of new names and lenghts

Comment: @TimPietzcker OK, let the email go, I want to check if a string has this pattern or not: *STRING*STRING*STRING#